# C error printing string from array of strings

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, c-strings

I am new a C an I am trying to get strings for array and I can't print them for some reason someone knows why?. Thank you

```
int main(void)
{

    int number_friends = 0, i = 0;
    printf("Enter number of friends: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_friends);
    getchar();
    char** friends = (char**)malloc(number_friends * sizeof(char*));
    get_friends_names(friends, number_friends);
    for (i = 0; i < number_friends; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", friends[i]);
    }
    free(friends);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void get_friends_names(char** friends, int size)
{
    char name[STR_LEN] = {0};
    int i = 0, len = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        fgets(name, STR_LEN, stdin);
        name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
        friends[i] = malloc(STR_LEN);
        friends[i] = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: `friends[i] = name;` You need to use `strcpy(friends[i], name);`

Comment: Also, it would be more efficient to only allocate the required space: `friends[i] = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);`

Comment: You should get into the habit of checking return codes, `scanf`, `malloc`, and `fgets` all return values you can use to check for success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet

```
    friends[i] = malloc(STR_LEN);
    friends[i] = name;
```

does not make a sense and has two drawbacks.

The first one is that there is a memory leak. That is a memory was allocated dynamically and its address was assigned to the pointer `friends[i]` And then the pointer was at once reassigned.

The second one is that you assigned to the pointer `friends[i]` the address of a local array that will not be alive after exiting the function.

You need to write at least like

```
friends[i] = malloc(STR_LEN);
strcpy( friends[i], name );
```

or

```
friends[i] = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
strcpy( friends[i], name );
```

Also in main you need to free all the allocated memory like

```
for (i = 0; i < number_friends; i++)
{
    free( friends[i] );
}
free(friends);
```

Pay attention to that the variable `len` is not used within the function.